# Warnings while installing PEAR modules, no results

Tags: php, iis-6, pear, mdb2

Running IIS 6, fastCGI, PHP 5.3.6 with PEAR MDB2.

I've installed this setup multiple times with no problem, but as of a couple of days ago when newly installing PHP on servers (this happened on more than one), I get to the point of installing the MDB2 package and I get the following:

> C:\Program Files\PHP>pear install MDB2
>
> Notice: Array to string conversion in PEAR\REST\13.php on line 80
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in PEAR\REST\13.php on line 84
>
> Warning: PEAR_REST_10::_returnDownloadURL(): It is not safe to rely on the syste
> m's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or th
> e date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods an
> d you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone id
> entifier. We selected 'America/Chicago' for '-5.0/DST' instead in PEAR\REST\10.p
> hp on line 263

In the end, MDB2 is not installed. I've tried installing other PEAR packages similarly and get the same warnings followed by no installation. Even `pear upgrade pear` results in the same behavior.

I've uninstalled and wiped PHP, re-downloaded the windows .msi installation file, re-installed and still run into the same thing.

Is there a registry item I should look into? Any idea what's going wrong here? Thanks for any thoughts.

Comment: Most probably, the errors were always there, but just surfaced due to other default error_reporting / display_errors settings.

Comment: I thought the same. But I forgot to add that MDB2 does not install. I'll edit the OP.

Comment: None of these look fatal. Have you run a `pear update pear`?

Comment: pear upgrade pear results in the exact same warnings and no action being taken.

Comment: I've uninstalled and wiped PHP, re-downloaded the windows .msi installation file, re-installed and still run into the same thing. Is there a registry item I should look into?

Comment: Have you wiped pear also? It doesn't use the registry BTW as far as I know. Does MDB2 not even get downloaded?

Comment: PEAR gets wiped when PHP does, since after uninstalling PHP I completely remove the directory (and PEAR is under PHP). MDB2 does not even get downloaded.

Comment: Then I'm stumped. No problems installing MDB2 here for that matter.

Comment: Thanks anyway. I appreciate the suggestions.

Comment: Just an idea: Maybe you've XDebug installed and set `xdebug.scream = 1`?

Comment: @KingCrunch: Would that prevent the MDB2 module from installing?

Comment: Good point: No, it wouldn't ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. After running `pear upgrade pear`, run `pear version` and verify that you are indeed using the new version. Sometimes the setup is fckd up and this does not work
2. Set the timezone in your `php.ini`.
3. Run the installation with many `-v` parameters, e.g. `pear -vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv install mdb2-beta` to get more output

Comment: fixed. -v has to be before install